# Create new publish profile: "One or more errors occurred"

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In a .NET project, select Build -> Publish -> and see the default "No profiles created, select a method" screen. Choose Folder and complete the wizard. Click Finish. Receive the following Microsoftian error:

"One or more errors occured"

With no other information.

**Having already solved this, I'm posting to share the answer and publicly shame Microsoft for these lame error messages. Visual Studio is a program only used by developers: we can handle a little more information, and in fact need it to solve these minor, job-derailing errors in a timely way and hold onto some sanity while the rest of the program is locking up and spewing errors all day.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Navigate to [Your project's directory] -> Properties -> Publish Profiles and delete the contents (or move to another location if you might want these back later). Then, in VS, click Finish in the publish profile wizard again.

Comment: Thank you. I had this come up after someone made a really bad commit, much easier to delete the whole thing then mess around for ages.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work for me with removing Properties.
On this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1105023/publish-wizard-throws-one-or-more-errors-occurred.html), Microsoft explains, that they have made a fix and advices instaling preview-version of Visual Studio 2019. Didn't work for me either.
I created a brand new MVC-project and tried to import publish profile, and it worked, so it looks like I have a problem in my original project.
Then I copied [Properties]>[PublishProfile] from new- to original project and th profile now works in original project.
After this copy, I then tried to make a new import in my original project, and that works too.
Not pretty at all, but I'm up and running again.